# Golang http serve file - giving parallel download support - contentLength & accept ranges not working

Tags: http, go, download, http-headers

Very new to **GoLang**, less than 10 days. I have a http server & i need to http serve files which are inside disk. Here in default this is using "net/http" http.ServeFile(w, r, file). **My problem is when i downloading these files, they don't have file pause/resume support but just downloading without showing total size.** I tried adding **"Content-Length" header & "Accept-Ranges" header**. But seems not working.

Http Headers i worrying about are,

- Content-Length
- Content-Type
- Accept-Ranges
- Content-Disposition (attachment)

I have *path to file*, *info* **FileInfo**, *w* **http.ResponseWriter**, *r* **http.Request** before serving function.First I tried adding

```
w.Header().Set("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
if w.Header().Get("Content-Encoding") == "" {
     w.Header().Set("Content-Length", strconv.FormatInt(info.Size(), 10))
}
```

to

```
func (s *Server) serveFiles(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
if strings.HasPrefix(r.URL.Path, "/download/") {
    url := strings.TrimPrefix(r.URL.Path, "/download/")
    //dldir is absolute
    dldir := s.state.Config.DownloadDirectory
    file := filepath.Join(dldir, url)
    //only allow fetches/deletes inside the dl dir
    if !strings.HasPrefix(file, dldir) || dldir == file {
        http.Error(w, "Nice try\n"+dldir+"\n"+file, http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    info, err := os.Stat(file)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "File stat error: "+err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    switch r.Method {
    case "GET":
        if info.IsDir() {
            w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/zip")
            w.WriteHeader(200)
            //write .zip archive directly into response
            a := archive.NewZipWriter(w)
            a.AddDir(file)
            a.Close()
        } else {
            w.Header().Set("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
            if w.Header().Get("Content-Encoding") == "" {
                w.Header().Set("Content-Length", strconv.FormatInt(info.Size(), 10))
            }
            http.ServeFile(w, r, file)
        }
```

**Then i can still see it is downloading without showing total size, doesn't have pause/resume support.**
i tried to download files from

sample small file: *https://s2.torrentfast.net/download/Dracula.2020.S01E01.HDTV.x264-PHOENiX[TGx]/[TGx]Downloaded%20from%20torrentgalaxy.to%20.txt*

sample big fig: *https://s2.torrentfast.net/download/Need%20For%20Speed%20Most%20Wanted%20Black%20Edition%20repack%20Mr%20DJ/Setup-1.bin*

[Http Get request response headers(sample small file) screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKEhL.png)

**Can help?**

Comment: i am trying now https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeContent method. Sample file may be not available at this moment because server rebuilding

Comment: still not solved

Answer (score 0):

`w.Header().Set("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")` is not required because Range will set `http.ServeFile` when responding.

`w.Header().Set("Content-Length", strconv.FormatInt(info.Size(), 10))` is wrong, may respond to transmission, and `http.ServerFile` will set this header.

The meaning of `Content-Length` is to specify the length of the body, and `Content-Range` will record the section of the transmission range and the total length information. **The correct method is to use `http.ServeFile` to send the file directly. The ServeFile function will automatically handle the situation of Range and Cache.**

Just look at the source code of `net/http/fs.go`.

Comment: can this happen(no pause/resume) if server is not responding to http HEAD requests?